# Can WebKit render to framebuffer via OpenGL ES, EGL or some other backend?

Tags: opengles

Is there any WebKit backend that can be used with Raspi for rendering with hardware acceleration?

Is it possible to use Cairo backend with OpenGL ES or something similar? I'm not very informed in that area so it may sound stupid, but the idea is to accelerate slow visual effects on webpages because of that overhead with CPU.

We know that WebKit is used on Android without X, so it should be possible somehow.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to go would probably to use [Qt embedded](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt-embedded-linux.html). It is small enough to run reasonably well on the Pi, I would guess. It can use the Linux framebuffer directly, without X11. If the kernel has acceleration in the framebuffer, it will use that, too. But this may not be the case on the Pi right now.

The Qt embedded can also be built with [QtWebKit](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtwebkit.html) support. There are some [Qt blog posts](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2012/01/19/raspberry-pi-a-case-study-in-deploying-qt-apps-to-generic-linux-devices/) about deploying Qt embedded on the Pi. You should begin there. There's also [cross compilation instructions](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2012/04/13/cross-compiling-qt-for-the-masses/) on the same blog to get you started.

Comment: Thanks! Too bad that there is no accelerated backend

Answer (score 0):

WebKit can actually be built to target Wayland for compositing/Drawing/tendering and bypass gtk entirely. Wayland has (some) support for rPI, so in theory this is doable with code in existence (no hacks). His would take full advantage of the wayland hardware acceleration and OpenGL support, too.